# Git Transport Error during push operation?

Tags: git, version-control

I am using Git Version Control witht he JGit Plugin for the eclipse IDE. when I changed the location of my repo, and when to push to the new repository. I am receiving the following error message.

```
Cant connect to any repository: 
git+ssh/username@remoteIPAddressgoeshere/srv/wma/git
Transport error occured during push operation: 
Java.IOException: Channel is Broken)
```

Comment: Can you try a clone from that new repo via command line, plain git client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though that has been reported in the EGit forum, there isn't yet a a bug report either in [egit bugs](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/buglist.cgi?classification=Technology;query_format=advanced;bug_status=UNCONFIRMED;bug_status=NEW;bug_status=ASSIGNED;bug_status=REOPENED;component=UI;product=EGit) or [jgit bugs](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/buglist.cgi?classification=Technology;query_format=advanced;bug_status=UNCONFIRMED;bug_status=NEW;bug_status=ASSIGNED;bug_status=REOPENED;component=JGit;product=JGit) (like there was for a [similar push error](http://code.google.com/p/egit/issues/detail?id=16))
So the right move would be to enter a bug in JGit with as many detail as you can (which is why I refer to this old Egit bug report as an example)